# How to retrieve "Marketing Cloud Administrator" Role with WSProxy/SOAP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Why can't I retrieve the "Marketing Cloud Administrator" Role using WSProxy or SOAP?  Have tried from parent BUs in multiple SFMC instances.  It's mysteriously absent.

If I drop filter and retrieve all Roles, it's not present in that result either.

I also tried this with a SSJS RetrieveRequest to no avail.

Here's my code:

```javascript
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
try {

    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var roleProps = ["Name","Description","CustomerKey","IsSystemDefined"];
    Write("<hr>roleProps: " + Stringify(roleProps));

    var roleObjsFilter0 = {Property: "IsSystemDefined", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value: true};
    var roleObjs0 = prox.retrieve("Role", roleProps, roleObjsFilter0);

    Write("<hr>roleObjs0.Results.length: " + roleObjs0.Results.length);

    var roles = roleObjs0.Results;

    for (k in roles) {
      Write("<hr>roles.Name:" +  roles[k].Name);
      Write("<br>roles.Description:" +  roles[k].Description);
      Write("<br>roles.CustomerKey:" +  roles[k].CustomerKey);
      Write("<br>roles.IsSystemDefined:" +  roles[k].IsSystemDefined);
    }

} catch(e) {

    Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e));

}
</script>
```

Roles from Setup:

[image: Roles from Setup]

Here's what I get for output:

[image: Retrieve Output]

Comment: It appears that the "newer" roles are not returned, You can retrieve the role ObjectIDs using dev tools when logged in, if that is helpful

Comment: You can get the return from the REST endpoint `https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/platform/v1/setup/quickflow/data` and that includes the Marketing Cloud Administrator role and the roleID. (This endpoint returns the Roles, Languages and TimeZones associated with the token)

Comment: I'm trying to audit roles & permissions for all AccountUser objects.  Even if I had all of the ObjectIDs, I don't think I'd be able to retrieve all of the associated Role objects.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not SOAP API or WSProxy, you can get the roleID (object ID) of each role via the REST API Endpoint:

```
GET /platform/v1/setup/quickflow/data
Host: {{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

This endpoint will return Timezones, Roles and Languages associated with the token context.

The roles includes:

- roleID (object ID)
- roleName (name shown in UI)
- description (description of role as shown in UI)

This returns an object of arrays of the 3 listed above. Below is a sample return (edited to make it easier to read)

```json
{
    "languages": [
        {
            "Key": "en-US",
            "Value": "English (United States)"
        },
        {
            "Key": "fr-CA",
            "Value": "French (Canada)"
        },
        {
            "Key": "fr-FR",
            "Value": "French (France)"
        },
        {
            "Key": "de-DE",
            "Value": "German (Germany)"
        }, 
    ...
    ],
    "roles": [
        {
            "roleID": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "roleName": "Administrator",
            "description": "Administrator"
        },
        {
            "roleID": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "roleName": "Analyst",
            "description": "Analyst"
        },
        {
            "roleID": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "roleName": "Content Creator",
            "description": "Content Creator"
        },
    ...
    ],
    "timeZones": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "description": "(GMT) Casablanca *"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "description": "(GMT) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London *"
        }, 
    ...
    ],
    "defaultUserData": {
        "defaultTimeZone": "79",
        "defaultLanguage": "en-US"
    }
}
```